# Expectation value of the electric field of a charged particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-fields

The nonrelativistic expression for the electric field of a charged particle from classical electrodynamics,

\begin{equation}
E(r) = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2},
\end{equation}

implies the particle is infinitely narrowly localized at a point, so it does not admit an uncertainty in the position of the particle.

In quantum mechanics, the particle is not infinitely narrowly localized at a point, but has a probability distribution in coordinate space $|\psi(r)|^2$.

What would be the nonrelativistic expression for the expectation value of the field $E$ at a point $r$, given $\psi(r)$ is known?

I have not been able to find the answer in textbooks or online.

@ T. ssP  I did not say that in the question, but I am interested in planar coordinates. The $r$ in my question seemed to imply I wanted spherical coordinates.

Based on your answer, would the expression I am looking for be, for the free particle in planar coordinates,

\begin{equation}
<\psi | E(r) | \psi> \ = \int \psi^* E(x) \psi \ dx = a \int \psi^* x^{-2} \psi \ dx
\end{equation}

where $a = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}$?

I wonder if the singular expression $\sim x^{-2}$ might cause problems in obtaining an expectation value.

*** I seem to get a glitch in posting comments, but I am able to edit my question so I comment briefly within (please bear with me). Perhaps someone may move the edit into a comment. It seems this question has now been answered.

Comment: See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/800767 .

Answer (score 2):

In general, the expression of the expectation value of the electric field is:
$$<E(r)> = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}<\Psi(r)|\frac{1}{r^2}|\Psi(r)>.$$
As can be seen, it depends on the wavefunction $\Psi(r)$ of the system. For example, you can apply it to the fundamental energy level of the Hydrogen atom, where its radial component is:
$$R_n(r) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi a_0^3}} e^{-r/a_0},$$

The expectation value of the electric field is then:
$$<R_n|E(r)|R_n> = \int^\infty_0 dr\ r^2R^*_n E(r) R_n.$$

A direct substitution of the expressions of the wavefunction yields:
$$<R_n|E(r)|R_n> = \frac{q}{2\pi^2\epsilon_0 a_0^3} \int^\infty_0 dr\ e^{-2r/a_0} = \frac{q}{4\pi^2\epsilon_0 a_0^2}.$$

The latter result make sense because the expectation value of the electric field in the fundamental level of the Hydrogen atom is the classical expression of the electric field evaluated in the bohr radius $a_0$.